# Почему возникает ошибка KeyError при попытке обратиться к столбцу таблицы?

Tags: python, pandas

Хочу собрать с википедии список городов и поместить их в список.

Делаю это через `pd.read_html()`. Получаю таблицу, но при попытке распечатать какой-либо столбец возникает ошибка.

Что я делаю не так?

Вот код:

```
import pandas as pd

url = r'https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8'
tables = pd.read_html(url)
cities = tables[0].rename(columns={'Город': 'city'})
#  cities.head()

print(cities['city'])
```

Ошибка очень длинная, не стал полностью прикреплять её, но суть в том, что там `KeyError: 'city'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этом случае следует правильно указать номер строки с заголовками (именами столбцов):

```
In [150]: tables = pd.read_html(url, header=[1])

In [151]: tables[0]
Out[151]:
         №  Герб      Город                Регион Федеральный округ Население Основание илипервое упоминание  Статус города[5]                           Прежние названия
0        1   NaN      Абаза               Хакасия         Сибирский     17111                           1867            1966.0      Абаканский Завод, Абаканско-Заводское
1        2   NaN     Абакан               Хакасия         Сибирский    165183                           1734            1931.0                  Усть-Абаканское (до 1931)
2        3   NaN   Абдулино  Оренбургская область       Приволжский     20663                           1795            1923.0                                        NaN
3        4   NaN     Абинск    Краснодарский край             Южный     34926                           1863            1963.0      Абинское (до 1863);Абинская (до 1962)
4        5   NaN    Агидель          Башкортостан       Приволжский     16365                           1980            1991.0                                        NaN
...    ...   ...        ...                   ...               ...       ...                            ...               ...                                        ...
1112  1113   NaN  Ярославль   Ярославская область       Центральный    591486                           1010            1071.0                                        NaN
1113  1114   NaN     Ярцево    Смоленская область       Центральный     47853                           1610            1926.0                                        NaN
1114  1115   NaN  Ясногорск      Тульская область       Центральный     16804                           1578            1958.0                          Лаптево (до 1965)
1115  1116   NaN      Ясный  Оренбургская область       Приволжский     16082                           1961            1979.0                                        NaN
1116  1117   NaN     Яхрома    Московская область       Центральный     13248                           1841            1940.0  Суровцево, посёлок Покровской мануфактуры

[1117 rows x 9 columns]
```

Answer (score 3):

Там двухуровневый мультииндекс, обращаться нужно так:

```
cities[('Города Российской Федерации','city')]
```

Можно было просто проверить `cities.columns`:

```
MultiIndex([('Города Российской Федерации',                              '№'),
            ('Города Российской Федерации',                           'Герб'),
            ('Города Российской Федерации',                           'city'),
            ('Города Российской Федерации',                         'Регион'),
            ('Города Российской Федерации',              'Федеральный округ'),
            ('Города Российской Федерации',                      'Население'),
            ('Города Российской Федерации', 'Основание илипервое упоминание'),
            ('Города Российской Федерации',               'Статус города[5]'),
            ('Города Российской Федерации',               'Прежние названия')],
           )
```